# Want to change the tab image for the current page

Tags: html, css, django, image, tabs

I have a django web app that has a horizontal navagation with tabs going horizontally. Each link looks for an image tab called tab.png. I've also included  a hover property as well.

Now, I want to change tab image for the selected tab menu (current page). So whatever the current page is, change the tab image to tab2.png. The only thing is I am not sure how to do this properly.

**base_menu.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<ol id="toc">
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.return_clients %}"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.quote_step1 %}"><span>Create quote/order</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.search_item %}"><span> Item Search</a></span></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.order_list %}"><span>Storage orders</span></a></li>
</ol>

<div id="right_content">
        {% block right_content %}

        {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.css**

```
ol#toc {
    height: 2em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol#toc li {
    background:#ffffff url(../images/tab.png);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;

}

ol#toc span {
    background: url(../images/tab.png) 100% 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

ol#toc a {
    color: #000000;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

ol#toc a:hover {
    background: url(../images/tab2.png);
    text-decoration: underline;`

}

ol#toc a:hover span {
    background: url(../images/tab2.png) 100% 0;
    background-position: 100% -120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this layout it doesnt seem to be possible using just css, since your 'li' or 'a' doesnt have something like id="current" .

Btw, using this style you can have an 'a' with a tab on top of a 'span' with a tab on top of a 'li' that has a tab. Kinda overkill id say?

This is the only css you need when you add a current li... all the other backgrounds are not needed.

```
ol#toc li {
    background:#ffffff url(../images/tab.png);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;

}
ol#toc li#current {
    background:#ffffff url(../images/tab2.png);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;

}
```

Comment: The problem is if I add `id="current"` to `<li><a href="{% url mmc.views.return_clients %}"><span>Home</span></a></li>`, It will make this link have `tab2.png, regradless if it is the current page or not. Is there a way to say if it is not the current page use tab.png?

Comment: Ok I have done what you have told me to do. The problem is that what is happening now is the link `<li id="current"><a href="{% url mmc.views.return_clients %}"><span>Home</span></a></li>' have a tab2.png image for its tab. Howeverif I go to a different page, it will say it is still the current page (i.e tabs do not change back to tab1.png images). How do I overcome this problem? Jscript, another template?

Answer (score 0):

@Shehzad009; Give your image in `a` tag & for `current page` you can create a class for it like `.current` $\&chane according to the page.

```
ol#toc a{background: url(http://dummyimage.com/200x32/000/fff&text=normal) 0 0;}
ol#toc a:hover, .current {background: url(http://dummyimage.com/200x32/000/454545&text=hover) 0 0;}
```

**HTML**

```
<ol id="toc">
        <li class="current"><a href="{% url mmc.views.return_clients %}"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.quote_step1 %}"><span>Create quote/order</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.search_item %}"><span> Item Search</a></span></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.order_list %}"><span>Storage orders</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a javascript line to set "current" class to .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $("#toc >li >a").each(function (key,object) { if($(object).attr("href") == document.location.pathname) $(object).addClass("current");});
  });
</script>
```